# Long Running Script IE vs Chrome/Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have checked some of the other threads about script times in IE, but I am having issues with a page I am working on. I have checked the network timers for loading the jquery/jqueryui, as well as other network calls, and neither seems to be the issue, even though i am doing a series of loads. However, my page loads up on Chrome and Firefox in about 0.5 seconds. On IE10, however, it takes upwards of 10 seconds. The same items appear to be cached, and like I said my `$(document).ready()` ajax call on the page load is slightly slower on IE (about 100ms slower), but it is still less than a second. Is there a way to diagnose what is actually taking so darn long?

Thanks!

Comment: The first possible culprit, to me, would be a long-running AJAX call not being properly set up. Try using the Network logging tab, and see if any one thing is being loaded during that entire 10 seconds. There's also a code-profiling tab where you can see if one function is running longer than necessary.

Comment: @Katana314 thanks for the answer! However, the network call doesn't appear to be the culprit; if anything IE actually runs the AJAX calls slightly faster. I have other pages that use the JQueryUI and haven't encountered issues having it (the dialog tool) load up on page load either. I have to say it is quite strange.

Answer (score 0):

It is the issue of jQuery to run slowly under IE10 for `$(document).ready()`.
Instead of debugging the issue, I suggest checking if your page using only one `$(document).ready()` will help.

Comment: Let me guess...Browser sniffing! My old nemesis!